# Is there a tool/method for permission introspection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So recently i ran into permission issues i struggle to track down. Is there a tool, or a some method to figure out why a permission was no granted.
How i imagine this to work:

```
sudo why <user> <command to test>  
sudo why voidcrawler touch foo
   voidcrawler is not the owner or part of groups: root, other_user
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld is a `bash` script that will show permissions and mounts from `/` to the files.

Comment: for `sudo`, or in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two parts to this and, that I'm aware of, no single tool that does both:

1. What was the command doing when it hit a permission denied error?
2. Why did that result in a permission denied error?

---

What was the command doing?

With a command like `rm`, it's usually pretty obvious but other commands have some fairly poor output and they don't actually tell you what the permission denied error was associated with.

The command [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) is pretty useful for this.  It lists all system calls issued and singanls received by a process.  Usefully it decodes some of this information into human readable output.

It writes everything to the stderr by default, but can be configured to write it to a file with the `-o` switch.

To give a simple example.  We can setup a trivial case to make `rm` fail with this:

```bsh
$ sudo mkdir foo
$ sudo touch foo/bar
$ rm -rf foo
rm: cannot remove 'foo/bar': Permission denied
```

To show how strace would help here we run the same `rm` command:

```bsh
$ strace -o trace_file rm -rf foo
$ grep EACCES trace_file
unlinkat(4, "bar", 0)                   = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

So this shows that the call to [unlinkat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlinkat) failed to delete a file `bar` from a directory it had already opened.

While we already knew this would be the case, we set it up to fail.  This can be useful for diagnosing more complex commands with poorer output.

---

I'm not aware of a tool which will determining why something resulted in a permission denied error, however there are relatively few reasons.

File permissions are by far the most common.  T[hese are well documented](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes) so not worth listing here.

The two other sources that can catch people out on a regular bases are:

- A Security manager (eg: [AppArmor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AppArmor))
- [fuse mounts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) used by a different user

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to check that on a command basis because you have to know what the command is about to do:

- Create a new file or directory
- Read an exisitng file
- Write an existing file
- Execute an existing file
- Delete or rename an existing file or directory
- Change to a directory

The permissions don't care which program tries these operations. The same command may do different things depending on its arguments or environment.